# Best practice to display script for JavaScript disabled browsers

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site which is only available to JavaScript enabled browsers.  What is the best way to provide a warning to non-JavaScript browsers?  Obviously entails using `<noscript>`, but I would appreciate a little more detail.  I was thinking of something like the following, but it does not work, nor even validate.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body class="wrap">
        <noscript>
            <h1>JavaScript is turned off in your web browser.<br />Turn it on to use this site, then refresh the page.</h1>
            <style type="text/css">
                body { display:none; }
                noscript { display:block !important; }
            </style>
        </noscript>
        HTML for JavaScript browsers goes here...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Drop any and all markup inside your `<noscript>` tag. It's a warning message for people who can't use your site, it doesn't need to be pretty. Also, `<style>` can't go there. Put it in your `<head>`. There is no reason to conditionally include it in the page, if you're conditionally rendering the element.

Comment: The style was there to not display the HTML meant for JavaScript users.  Would you recommend just putting a huge <h1>Hey you!</h1>, and then still display all the normal HTML meant for JavaScript users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling javascript, then reload Stackoverflow. That is a nice clean way to ask users to enable javascript.

Then render the site as best you can. Don't worry about hiding your page content for javascript disabled browsers.

Comment: Did so, and saw the following at the top nice and small: "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled".  I don't want to set expectations that the site will work but not at optimum performance without JavaScript, but make it very obvious that they need to enable JavaScript.

Comment: Why not change the wording of the message to be very clear? Rather than trying to be draconian, I think having a clear message is about as good as you can be expected to do.

Comment: Agree with the wording, but when I looked at Stack Overflow without JS enabled (nice example by the way!), I might have missed it if I was drinking too much.

Comment: My title and question was unclear.  Thank you for your response.  I will select yours as the correct answer, and repost more specific.  Thanks