# How should I hide HTML for non-JavaScript enabled browsers?

Tags: html, css

How should I hide HTML for non-JavaScript enabled browsers?  I was thinking of something like the following, but it does not work with my FF browser, nor even validate. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body class="wrap">
        <noscript>
            <h1>JavaScript is turned off in your web browser.<br />Turn it on to use this site, then refresh the page.</h1>
            <style type="text/css">
                body { display:none; }
                noscript { display:block !important; }
            </style>
        </noscript>
        HTML for JavaScript only browsers goes here...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) method is quite smart.  Start with a class on your body of `no-js`.  This class is then removed when the JavaScript kicks in.

Comment: You are hiding the body element when your `<noscript>` is within the body element also.

Comment: @Lavabeams.  Good point!  I guess I can include a new DIV for only JS content.  Was just trying to be cleaver and do it without.

Comment: @Brad including modernizr for such a small requirement is a huge overhead.

Comment: @Lavabeams, I'm not suggesting including Modernizr... just saying that the method used is a solid way to do it.  I agree, no point in a library for simply removing a class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to display script for JavaScript disabled browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262105/best-practice-to-display-script-for-javascript-disabled-browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be like this

```
<body class="wrap">

    <noscript>

        <h1>JavaScript is turned off O_o</h1>

        <style type="text/css">

            .onlyscript { display:none; }

        </style>

    </noscript>

    <div class="onlyscript">HTML for JavaScript only browsers goes here...</div>

</body>
```

Cuz this

```
        <style type="text/css">
            body { display:none; }
            noscript { display:block !important; }
        </style>
```

is really confusing construction and unjustified "!important;" use. That can cause problems in future.
It's better to be plain instead of making smartass bug farms :)